# different key press events - different actions. How to? + 3D and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, keypress

Js noob here/

it's a question about several keypress events, and how to bind them to different actions.

I've got this thing here:

```
var imga = ["http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236128/1_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236128/2_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236128/3_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236128/4_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236128/5_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236128/6_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236128/7_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236128/8_t.jpg",
];
var imgb = ["http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236316/1_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236316/2_t.jpg",
"http://img1.jpegbay.com/gallery/004236316/3_t.jpg"
];
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
if (e.keyCode == "65") {
    changeImage(-1);
}
if (e.keyCode == "66") {
    changeImage(-1);
}
};

function changeImage(dir) {
var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
img.src = imga[imga.indexOf(img.src)+dir] || imga[(dir==1) ? 0 :         imga.length-1];
var img = document.getElementById("b");
img.src = imgb[imgb.indexOf(img.src)+dir] || imgb[(dir==1) ? 0 : imgb.length-1];
```

}

it's on jsfiddle also:

http://jsfiddle.net/k3wxhc58/39/

so two letters, two image batches, the top one is connected to the A button,
and the other one should be connected to the B button,
key press makes images change

i want to make the whole alphabet.

one more thing, 
in general, is it a smart way to do this typographical animation?
i rendered it as a 3d object, so i was wondering is it better to use the THREE.js library and import my 3d model as a JSON? and somehow manipulate it in that way?

no previous coding experience, everything what you see are bits of what i've glued together by googling stuff.

thanks in advance guys

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For keyboard, it's a matter of preference. What you did is good for a few keys and I assume you know that you are using 'keydown' so the action is triggered once by each time the key is pressed. Depending on the need (I want the action to be triggered once or as long as the key is down, the number of keys I want to listen to and if I want them to work simultaneously or not) I use different methods:

One of the easiest ways is using THREEx.KeyboardState if you want to use Three.js: http://learningthreejs.com/data/THREEx/docs/THREEx.KeyboardState.html

Or:

1. When there the number of buttons are high but each of them are supposed to be pressed separately, the `switch`statement is very helpful: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

   ```
   switch(e.keyCode){
      case 65:
          //do this
          break; 
      case 66:
          ...
   }
   ```
2. When it's important to press some keys together, you can create an object then add the pressed keys in it. Other functions acquire status from the object:

   ```
   var down_keys = {}
   document.addEventListener( "keydown" , function(e){
       down_keys[ e.keyCode ] = true;
   })

   document.addEventListener( "keyup" , function(e){
       down_keys[ e.keyCode ] = false;
   })
   ```
3. A combination of these two

---

About the second question: For high resolutions, slide by slide animation would be impractical. Also you limit the frame rate. Personally, I don't see any advantages in using pictures to create the animation instead of using three.js